# How to reset Contents and Settings in an OS X app?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, core-data

I need to reset by database and userdefaults value in my OS X app. How can I do it? In IOS app we have an option like '**Reset contents and settings**'. But I don't see such an option when I run OS X app. What I'm doing right now is, drill down to /users/library and delete the .storedata file under my project folder. But with this method I am not able to reset my userdefaults value. Is there any other way out? I am new to OS X programing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manually nil the values of your NSUserDefaults and delete the database al-together and then recreate it. Best option would be to include an empty database and copy it over to the Library folder (or wherever you access it) if it does not exist.

Comment: Thank you man! This is exactly what I am doing right now. I was looking for a 'single button action' which could perform both operations.

Comment: You can use a "single button action" and perform both tasks.

Comment: @WrightCS. Did you mean that we can achieve it by writing the code ourself? But is was not what I am looking for. I am looking for something like iphone's "Reset Contents and settings" option within the xcode. The point is I may need to start a fresh app very often. At that time i may need to reset all these values. It would have been very helpful if xcode provides me a "Reset Contents and Settings". But as you mentioned, unfortunately Xcode is not showing this option for OS X app :-( and we need to do all these manually

Comment: Yes, there's no magic feature. You need to write this yourself. Welcome to programming.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in a DebugViewController:

```
- (void)removeUserDefaults {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary] forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
}
```

Then I can delete the UserDefaults with a Button-Press.